# Website google maps zipcode search

Tags: php, maps, netsuite

First off, I'm a beginning programmer.

In the past we have used "WordPress" for all of our web displays but have moved to a program called "Netsuite" because of business reasons.

We have implemented Google maps before with our "WordPress" website with no issues but for some reason we just aren't getting it to work right within "Netsuite".

WordPress was a lot easier to manage and design for a beginner but "Netsuite" has shown to be a total different beast.

We want it to where someone can put in a zip code and Google maps returns all available stores in the radius selected by the customer. At the moment it does not do anything.

Here's the code that has been used in the "Item/Category" portion of Netsuite = https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=68100&c=474317&h=6cc7936ec76825098acc&mv=ht7pyjtk&_xt=.txt&whence=

Please any help is grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the call inside NetSuite using a Suitelet - this can be called from the UI. Use nlapiRequestURL to get the JSON data and process it as you do on your file there.

Also, it's not best practice to disclose your company number c=xxxxxxx on the URL.